# Access User's Possible Screen Resolutions - C# 2010

Tags: c#-4.0, screen, resolution, screen-resolution

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am wondering how I might go about accessing the screen resolutions available on a user's PC. I would like to get a list of all available resolutions and also determine what the user is current running at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can make a **PInvoke** call to **EnumDisplaySettings** api call in User32.dll.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings (string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode );
```

See example [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumdisplaysettings).

You'll of course run into complications with dual-monitor systems, but to get the current screen you can do

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
```

I assumed you were talking about an executable and not an ASP.Net app, but if you need the screen size in Javascript, you can use the **screen** object.

```
screen.width; screen.height; screen.colorDepth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *Microsoft.Win32* *`RegestryKey`* class to fetch the current screen size from the registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Hardware Profiles\...
```

I'd hunt around there to find what you want, but I wouldn't mess with whatever settings they have in there.