# How to change AMD/ATI Catalyst settings + screen resolution?

Tags: c#, screen, screen-resolution

I need to change my screen resolution programmatic way from 2560x1440 to 1680x1050, and set AMD Catalyst to "center picture" mode. I am tired of repeating this process and revert back always before I start gaming. I can't afford better or more GPUs to handle the performance issues. My current situation works fine except that it's painful.

I am looking for C# code since that's the desktop language I know best.

Comment: Yo' cc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727688/how-to-set-the-windows-screen-resolution-using-c-sharp-windows-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039651/access-users-possible-screen-resolutions-c-sharp-2010

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Joshy_geo/changescreenresolution10102006112110AM/changescreenresolution.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of changing resoultion:

You can use `EnumDisplayDevices` to check displays you have available and `EnumDisplaySettings` to list available resolutions for your displays. 
Then use `ChangeDisplaySettings` to set the resolution you need.